# Azure App Service Push - registration endpoint

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Im trying to implement push notifications on Xamarin iOS project using Azure App Service Push, and I'm having problems with device failing to register.

The confusing part is this:

I've read https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/concepts/
and it basically says that

> The /push/installations endpoint is part of App Service Push - a feature of the Azure App Service resource. This exists on your .azurewebsites.net domain. It is not part of Notification Hubs.

However, according to this post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/01/10/azure-mobile-apps-net-sdk-releases/

.AddPushNotifications() (which actually adds /push/installations endpoint)is now deprecated:

> You should use the App Service Push endpoint instead. In your ASP.NET Owin Startup class, you can remove the reference to .AddPushNotifications() from the configuration.

Details here: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/What-is-a-Default-Configuration%3F

If I understand correctly my App Service Mobile App, once connected to Push via Notification hub should expose some kind of endpoint for device registration but I find it unclear what that endpoint is and do i need to manually create it in mobile backend app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.AddPushNotifications()` is used to support the Azure Notification Hubs push registration endpoint via the [Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/) package, you could check the [NotificationInstallationsController.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/blob/04d75cadc137cc478f98edfa1fa5b868e5548dfd/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Notifications/Controllers/NotificationInstallationsController.cs) under the previous package. And at this point, you need to specific the `Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.ConnectionString` app setting with the value for the connection string to your notification hub.

While the App Service Push is a feature provided by Azure Portal, and you need to go to your app service and click "Settings > Push", then choose your notification hub for your app, more details you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#configure-hub).

For your mobile client, you could leverage the extension method `GetPush` for `IMobileServiceClient` under [MobileServiceClientExtensions.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/11c9bcd3c1e16a32cff27460ef836888cbd2d9fa/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Platforms/ios/Extensions/MobileServiceClientExtensions.cs) and the [PushHttpClient.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/blob/8f0fc245f29c5b3245ce27e8428b0f4a90b948bc/src/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/Push/PushHttpClient.cs) to send requests against `push/installations` for you. For more detailed code snippet, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push#configure-and-run-the-ios-project-optional). Also, you could refer to adrian hall's book about using the `.InvokeApiAsync()` method.

Comment: .AddPushNotifications() is deprecated isnt it?

Comment: AFAIK, it is deprecated. But the endpoint is still in the package, it may be removed in the future version. You should configure the Push under your mobile app via Azure Portal, and remove the reference to `.AddPushNotifications()` from the Owin startup class.

Comment: Is there any online documentation on how to corretly implement this using App Service Push? All I can see, and all that is linked here is obsolete, event the book by Adrian Hall ( which is referenced multiple times )